# Runtime cost of Ethiopian Multiplication algorithm

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, binary

The [Ethiopian multiplication algorithm](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Ethiopian_multiplication#:%7E:text=Ethiopian%20multiplication%20is%20a%20method,the%20top%20of%20two%20columns.&text=Sum%20the%20values%20in%20the,the%20original%20two%20numbers%20together) is a way of finding the product of two numbers without using multiplication. Let's say we want to multiply 35 by 88. The algorithm goes like this

\begin{array}{rr|r}
               & 35 & 88   \\
               & 17 & 176  \\
               &  [8] & [352]  \\
               &  [4] & [704]  \\
               &  [2] & [1408] \\
               &  1 & 2816 \\ 
               &    &      \\ \hline
               &    &  3080  \\ 
\end{array}
We list the numbers in two columns and we divide the first by 2 at each step until we reach 1 and multiply the other by 2 at each step. Then we sum down the second column ignoring those which has a corresponding even number from the first column. so $3080=88+176+2816$. How do we calculate the running time of this algorithm?

Comment: How many lines contains your list and how many bits has the number 35?

Comment: this was a hint how to solve the general question: relate the length of the list to the number of bits of your starting number

Comment: In german it is called "Russische Bauernmultiplikation", which could be translated to "Russian farmer-multiplication" , but I do not know whether it is common under this English name.

Comment: @Peter Many ancient civilizations had this method, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20ancient%20Egyptian%20multiplication,require%20the%20multiplication%20table%2C%20only) lists few

Comment: I think the complexity is $O(\log_2(a))$ when we consider $a\times b$.

Comment: I do not think that we get the proper complexity if we consider doubling or adding two numbers as a single step.